# .htaccess redirection with non existant folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect the following two URLs as shown:

`http://domain.com/folder/file.php -> http://domain.com/folder2/`
`http://damain.com/folder/file2.php?id=13 -> http://domain.com/folder2/`

Normally I would have used something like:
`RewriteRule ^/folder/file\.php /hackme/ [R]`

But it seems that, as "folder" does not exist, the redirection cannot take pleace. Can somebody help me figure out how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder/file\.php folder2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=13$
RewriteRule ^folder/file2\.php folder2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to work. the fact that neither "folder" nor "file.php" exist seems to be a problem. if i use existing folders and files it seems to work

Comment: not it is not a problem if they don't exists, what error do you get ? what do you have else in your htaccess ?

Comment: i have removed everything else from htaccess. the error i get is "Object not found!"

Comment: doest folder2 exists ? and is it in the root web directory ?

Comment: if you are getting "Object not found!" and not "File not found!" then your problem may be from something else and not the htaccess rule :/
if you access folder2 directly, does it work properly ?

Comment: i have found the issue. apparently xampp uses a folder with the same name as i am and there was confusion there. testing it on the live system worked perfectly